# Problem with apt autoremove, distro wants to remove nvidia related packages and detected theme useless

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management

After removing ghostscript witch ruined my system, I install new fresh Ubuntu. Every time that I want to install something I get following warning:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libfwupdplugin1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libnvidia-cfg1-470 libnvidia-common-470
  libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-extra-470
  libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxnvctrl0 linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30
  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-30-generic
  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-30-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-30-generic nvidia-compute-utils-470
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-470 screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
```

I don't know why Ubuntu wants to remove everything related to my graphic card NVIDIA?
Are these packages important ? How I should save theme or turn this warning off?
I had this problem once before by removing **ghostscript** package witch removed almost every core package I needed. Now I'm scared to remove these too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like many of those packages were installed as dependencies and are no longer needed. You can manually install the packages you want to keep.

For example:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libfwupdplugin1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libnvidia-cfg1-470 libnvidia-common-470 libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-470 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
```

This will explicitly install everything except for the kernel related packages. The kernel related packages are usually outdated when a newer kernel version is released. Next time, the message should only contain kernel related packages and you can safely run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove them.

Comment: Thank you very much dear friend. I found out how it works and worked.